# Get (X,Y) Pixel color from drawn Vertex & Color array in OPENGL

Tags: object, opengl, pixel, alpha, vertex

I would like to get a pixel color or a drawn object in OpenGL. For example, if I draw a circle to the context, it will be held and drawn in a object class. It will have a width and height. And if I click on the circle, it should return the color. BUT... if I click toward the corner of the object, it should return alpha 0 to let me know I have clicked on the circle object, but in a transparent area of the object. Do I need to draw to a Pixel Buffer Object?

[image]

```
 void Circle::Display()
 {

      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
      glPushMatrix();

      glEnable(GL_BLEND);
      glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
      glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

      glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, circle_vectors);
      glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, circle_colors);

      glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

      glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
      glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY); // enables the color-array.
      glDisable(GL_BLEND);

      glPopMatrix();
 }


 bool Circle::IsTransparent(int x, int y)
 {
      //We clicked on the circle object. Is the pixel transparent?
 }
```

Comment: If this is a circle, why not use the general representation? You know the radius, just test if a point is within r-units from the center of the circle. No need to read the object at all. Do you do any arbitrary scaling?

Comment: After giving it a little more thought, I take it you're texture-mapping this circle onto a simple quad? And you want to know if a point lies within the circle region of the quad? As long as you're not transforming the quad unusually you ought to still be able to use the approach I mentioned above ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the general form for any simple geometric shape first and foremost. Circles, squares, triangles, etc... you can find if a point is within the bounds of all of these with some simple math. So if at all possible, subclass your Shape class to speed up testing against simple shapes.

For arbitrary shapes, or shapes with unusual transform characteristics you *may* need to do a pixel read-back or maybe an occlusion query.